# why I cannot use "run Android lint" from menu "Window" in Eclipse in toolbar I can run it, is it OK?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-lint

I have just updated SDK and ADT for eclipse and now there is one thing confused me:
I cannot use "Run Android Lint" from menu "Window".
But I can run it from eclipse toolbar or richt-click on my project, then "Android tools" -- "run lint". 
I'm not sure if this is a bug from Android or I have done something wrong by updating. 
Hat anybody the same problem as I?
Thank you!

With best regards,
Katrina

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of running it from Window, right-click on your project in Project Explorer and, from Android Tools **Run Lint:  Check for Common Errors**

Note that before you do this it may be necessary to do a "Clear Lint Markers" via the same menu.